# Exporting ListView content to Excel?

Tags: interop, c#-3.0, excel-interop

I've been trying to export the content data of my ListView control into an Excel application using C#. I've already done this before using VB.NET and I tried to convert my code to C# but it failed but I made a modification on it and seems everything is fine on code below except for the last part which to save the data as an excel file. I need an assistance to modify this code correctly. I would greatly appreciate your helpful response.

The code below that got an error is:

```
oBook.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.ToString() + SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Error   5   No overload for method 'SaveAs' takes '1' arguments

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int row2 = 0;
    int col2 = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int ctr = 0;

    ctr = 0;
    row2 = 1;
    col2 = 3;

    row = 3;
    col = 3;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oExcel.Visible = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oExcel.ActiveSheet;


    SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx|Word File|*.doc|Text File|*.txt";
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save As";

    if (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
         switch (SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
         {
            case 1:
            {
                for (ch = 1; ch <= ListView1.Columns.Count; ch++)
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[row2, col2] = ListView1.Columns[ctr].Text;

                    col2 = col2 + 1;
                    ctr = ctr + 1;
                }

                foreach (ListViewItem lview in ListView1.Items)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lview2 in lview.SubItems)
                    {
                        oSheet.Cells[row, col] = lview2.Text;
                        col = col + 1;
                    }

                    col = 3;
                    row = row + 1;
                }

                oBook.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.ToString() + SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
                oExcel.Quit();
                SaveFileDialog1.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfully saved", string.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workbook [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method takes 11 parameters.  In C# you have to pass something for these optional parameters even if you do not care about them.  The easiest thing to do here is pass `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` for those you do not care about.  It is a pain though.